# Flutter Password and Confirm Password Validation

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working to build an app and I wanted to include password validation. Specifically, I want to have a user's password match the confirmed password they type in, then a circle will turn green when they match. I have gotten it to work for password length and special characters, but I am not able to get it to work for password confirmation matching. Could someone please provide some advice or insight on what I could attempt to do?

I have attached my entire code down below:

```
class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();

}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  TextEditingController _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();
  bool showPassword = false;
  bool _isPasswordEightLetters = false;
  bool _OneNumberPassword = false;
  bool _confirmPassword = false;
  TextEditingController _emailTextController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  OnPasswordChanged(String password) {
    
    final numericRegex = RegExp(r'[0-9;]');

    setState(() {

      _isPasswordEightLetters = false;
      if (password.length >= 8) {
        _isPasswordEightLetters = true;
      }

      _OneNumberPassword = false;
      if(numericRegex.hasMatch(password)) {
        _OneNumberPassword = true;
      }

     _confirmPassword = false;
      if (password == _confirmPasswordController.text) {
        _confirmPassword = true;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),),
                            child: const Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
                              size: 15,
                              color: Color(0xff31708c),
                            ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Text("Create Account",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: const Color(0xff31708c),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontSize: 28),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  const Text("Create an account with one of the following options:",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff31708c),
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 165,
                        height: 50,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/Google_-G-_Logo.svg.png',
                          height: 35,
                          ),
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.08),
                            border: Border.all(color: const Color(0x6630728c)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
                          ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 30,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 165,
                        height: 50,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/facebook-logo.png',
                          height: 35,
                          ),
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.08),
                              border: Border.all(color: const Color(0x6630728c)),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 10.0),
                            child: const Divider(
                              color: Color(0xff31708c),
                              height: 60,
                              thickness: 1.5,
                            )),
                        ),
                        const Text("or continue with",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff31708c),
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),

                        Expanded(child: Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 15.0),
                          child: const Divider(
                            color: Color(0xff31708c),
                            height: 60,
                            thickness: 1.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                        )
                      ],
                      ),
                      // const SizedBox(
                      //   height: 10,
                      // ),
                      Text(
                        "Email Address",
                        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: const Color(0xff31708c),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _emailTextController,
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          // inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          //   FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))
                          // ],
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Enter Your Email Address",
                            hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xff31708c),
                            fontSize: 15.5),
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.email_sharp,
                            color: Color(0xff31708c)),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0x6630728c))),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0x6630728c),
                              ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.email]
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.08),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Text("Create a Password",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                        color: const Color(0xff31708c),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 15),),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField
                          (onChanged: (password) => OnPasswordChanged(password),
                          controller: _passwordTextController,
                            obscureText: !showPassword,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                             color: Colors.black),
                             decoration: InputDecoration(
                               hintText: "Please Create a Password",
                               suffixIcon: InkWell(
                                 onTap: () {
                                   setState(() {
                                     showPassword = !showPassword;
                                   });
                                 },
                                 child: Icon(
                                   showPassword
                                   ? Icons.visibility
                                   : Icons.visibility_off,
                                   color: const Color(0xff31708c)
                                 ),
                               ),
                               hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                 color: Color(0xff31708c),
                                 fontSize: 15.5),
                                 prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.password_sharp,
                                 color: Color(0xff31708c),),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0x6630728c))),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0x6630728c))
                                  ) 
                             ),
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.08),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          ),
                           const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Text("Confirm Password",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                        color: const Color(0xff31708c),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 15)),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField
                          (controller: _confirmPasswordController,
                          onChanged: (value) => _confirmPasswordController,
                            obscureText: !showPassword,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                             color: Colors.black),
                             decoration: InputDecoration(
                               hintText: "Confirm Your Password",
                               suffixIcon: InkWell(
                                 onTap: () {
                                   setState(() {
                                     showPassword = !showPassword;
                                   });
                                 },
                                 child: Icon(
                                   showPassword
                                   ? Icons.visibility
                                   : Icons.visibility_off,
                                   color: const Color(0xff31708c)
                                 ),
                               ),
                               hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                 color: Color(0xff31708c),
                                 fontSize: 15.5),
                                 prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.password_sharp,
                                 color: Color(0xff31708c)),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0x6630728c))),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0x6630728c))
                                  ) 
                             ),
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.08),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 18,),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              AnimatedContainer(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                width: 20,
                                height: 20,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: _isPasswordEightLetters ? Colors.green : Colors.transparent,
                                  border: _isPasswordEightLetters ? Border.all(color: Colors.transparent) :
                                  Border.all(color: const Color(0x6630728c)),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
                                ),
                                child: const Center(
                                  child: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white, size: 15,),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 10,),
                              const Text("Contains at least 8 characters",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff31708c),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              AnimatedContainer(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                width: 20,
                                height: 20,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: _OneNumberPassword ? Colors.green : Colors.transparent,
                                  border: _OneNumberPassword ? Border.all(color: Colors.transparent) :
                                  Border.all(color: const Color(0x6630728c)),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
                                ),
                                child: const Center(
                                  child: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white, size: 15),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 10,),
                              const Text("Contains at least 1 number",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff31708c),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              AnimatedContainer(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                width: 20,
                                height: 20,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: _confirmPassword ? Colors.green : Colors.transparent,
                                  border: Border.all(color: const Color(0x6630728c)),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
                                ),
                                child: const Center(
                                  child: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white, size: 15),
                                ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(width: 10,),
                                const Text("Passwords match",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff31708c),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                    height: 25),
                    ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 55,
                      buttonColor: const Color(0xff31708c),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                            email: _emailTextController.text, 
                            password: _passwordTextController.text).then((_) {
                              print('New Account Created');
                          Navigator.of(context).
                          pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AccountOnboarding())); //CHANGE TO ACCOUNT SETUP
                          }
                      ).onError((error, stackTrace) {
                        print('Error');
                      });
                      },
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: const Text("Sign Up",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 70,
                        ),
                        const Text("Already have an account?",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff31708c),
                        fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const LoginScreen2()));
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            " Login here",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff31708c),
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: replace  onChanged: (value) => _confirmPasswordController, with onChanged: (confirmPassword) => OnPasswordChanged(_passwordTextController.text),


here  passing  _passwordTextController.text because in this method you are using parameter as password and accessing  confirmpassword via controller, and before you were wrongly updating confirm password controller with string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
 onChanged: (value) => _confirmPasswordController,
```

with

```
onChanged: (confirmPassword) => OnPasswordChanged(_passwordTextController.text),
```

Note:

here passing _passwordTextController.text because in this method you are using parameter as password and accessing confirmpassword via controller, and before you were wrongly updating confirm password controller with string